# Capture screen and find reference image

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I'm trying to do the following in python:

1. Capture the screen
2. If the screenshot contains a given reference image (can be jpg or pgn), get the coordinates of this image on the screen

Further information:

- The reference image won't be huge (5x5 pixel will be enough)
- It should be as fast as possible, since it should constantly scan the screen
- if possible: work on Windows and Linux

What is the best way, I can achieve this in python?

Edit:
Thank to Leo Antunes, I made the following solution working:

```
def bitmap2brg(bmp):
  w = bmp.width;
  h = bmp.height;
  a = np.empty((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8);

  for r in xrange(h):
    for c in xrange(w):
      v = bmp.get_color(c, r);
      a[r, c, 2] = (v >> 16) & 0xFF;
      a[r, c, 1] = (v >> 8) & 0xFF;
      a[r, c, 0] = v & 0xFF;
  return a;

def grabScreen():
  THRESHOLD = 1

  # reference image
  needle = cv2.imread('img_top_left.png')
  needle_height, needle_width, needle_channels = needle.shape

  # Grabbing with autopy
  screen = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
  haystack = bitmap2brg(screen)

  # work through the frame looking for matches above a certain THRESHOLD
  # and mark them with a green circle
  matches = 0
  for pt in np.transpose(np.where(cv2.matchTemplate(haystack, needle, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) >= THRESHOLD)):
      cv2.circle(haystack, (pt[1] + needle_width/2, pt[0] + needle_height/2), 10, (0,255,0))
      matches += 1

  # display the altered frame
  print "Number of matches: {}".format(matches)
  cv2.imshow('matches', haystack)
  if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: with a great find from the OP himself ([autopy](http://www.autopy.org)), the "right" solution becomes very simple:

```
import autopy

needle = autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open('needle.png')

while True:
        haystack = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
        found = haystack.find_every_bitmap(needle)
        print(found)
```

*Original sub-optimal answer below*:

---

You can do this sort of operations on video relatively easily with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org).
The only problem is capturing the screen in a portable manner. The only theoretically portable library I could find was [this one](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot), but I couldn't get it to work.

Instead of a truly portable library, I hacked a solution around ffmpeg that works on linux, and which [theoretically could be made to work on Windows and OSX as well](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess

THRESHOLD = 0.7

# your reference image
needle = cv2.imread('/path/to/some/needle.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
needle_height, needle_width = needle.shape

width, height = (800, 600) # you could of course detect this

command = [ '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
        '-f', 'x11grab',
        '-i', ':0.0+0,0',
        '-r', '3', # lower frame-rate for testing
        '-s', '%dx%d' % (width, height),
        '-f', 'rawvideo',
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
        '-']

pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

while(True):
    # get a frame
    raw = pipe.stdout.read(width*height*3)
    # format it into a matrix which can be worked on by openCV
    original = np.fromstring(raw, dtype='uint8').reshape((height, width, 3))
    pipe.stdout.flush()

    # transform it to grayscale for the matching
    haystack = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # work through the frame looking for matches above a certain THRESHOLD
    # and mark them with a green circle
    for pt in np.transpose(np.where(cv2.matchTemplate(haystack, needle, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) >= THRESHOLD)):
        cv2.circle(original, (pt[1] + needle_width/2, pt[0] + needle_height/2), 10, (0,255,0))

    # display the altered frame
    cv2.imshow('matches', original)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note that the magical "3" used during reading from the pipe comes from ffmpeg's output pixel format: bgr**24**.

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't get the ffmpeg version to work since I'm on my windows machine at the moment. But I found a library called autopy which should be platform independend and with some small changes, it worked with your solution! So again, thank you very much for your efforts and your help! I will try to edit my working solution in my question as it seems i cannot post it in this comment

Comment: @ForceOfWill: nice find with [autopy](http://www.autopy.org)! I had obviously never heard of it! :) But since its Bitmap class even has a helpful `find_every_bitmap()` method, the "right" solution then becomes embarrassingly simple! ;) I'll update my answer with it.